# missing 1 required positional argument error whith solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, ode, solver

I am trying to simulate the movement of a vehicle  using python and I'm using *solve_ivp*
to resolve the ODE
here's my code down below

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.integrate, math ,random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def vehicleDynamics(t, x , v):   
    u      = max(2.0, 0.3*t)
    vcoeff = random.randint(0, 40) * t   
    return [v[0] * math.sin(x[2]), v[0] * math.cos(x[2]), v[0], u ,vcoeff]


# Initial State
x  = [0 ,0, 1]
v  = [1.2]

# Time points for drawing
timePointsOfInterest = numpy.linspace(0, 15, 2000)

# Evaluate ODE
odeResult = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(vehicleDynamics, (0.0, 15.0 )  ,x   ,t_eval=timePointsOfInterest)
assert odeResult.success

# Plot
plt.plot(odeResult.y[0], odeResult.y[1])
plt.xlabel("X Position")
plt.ylabel("Y Position")
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()
```

but I keep getting the following compile error :

```
TypeError: vehicleDynamics() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v'
```

Am I missing anything here,  how to pass the parameter properly

Comment: `vehicleDynamics` is going to be called by passing 2 arguments to it but you defined it to get 3

Comment: @abc thanks , how to pass the third parameter ?

Comment: What is supposed to represent the 3rd one? The signature of the function `vehicleDynamics `should be something like`fun(t, y)`.

Comment: What's this `v` that you use in `vehicleDynamics`?  I see `x` the initial state, and time specs, but nothing like `v`.  `solve_ivp` takes an `args` argument.  Read about that in the docs - carefully.

Comment: @abc the third one should represent the speed

Comment: It is not visible what the dynamical system is that you are trying to solve. `x[0],x[1]` are the position variables, `x[2]` is the angle of the motion direction, `v[0]` is the speed. What is the 5th component? What is the role of `u` and `vcoeff`?

Comment: Add the argument `args=(v,)` to the `solve_ivp` call.  (Requires SciPy version 1.4.)